# Symfony and doctrine getting null response from sql database query

Tags: php, mysql, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

How do I query the mySql DB? For some reason I am not getting the response I expect below.

I have a `message` table with a `messageBody` column that I would like to get.

I am also trying to return it as an array of JSON formatted objects.

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/messages")
 * @Template()
 */
public function messagesGetAction()
{

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Message');
    $messagesArr = $repository->findBy(array('messageBody'=>'messageBody'));
    $messages = json_encode($messagesArr);

    return new Response($messages);

}
```

This is what is returned

```
[{},{},{}]
```

My question is how do I build a proper get controller to return an api json response?

*Message entity*

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="message")
 */
class Message
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $fromUser;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $toUser;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $messageTitle;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $messageBody;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set fromUser
     *
     * @param string $fromUser
     * @return Message
     */
    public function setFromUser($fromUser)
    {
        $this->fromUser = $fromUser;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fromUser
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFromUser()
    {
        return $this->fromUser;
    }

    /**
     * Set toUser
     *
     * @param string $toUser
     * @return Message
     */
    public function setToUser($toUser)
    {
        $this->toUser = $toUser;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get toUser
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getToUser()
    {
        return $this->toUser;
    }

    /**
     * Set messageTitle
     *
     * @param string $messageTitle
     * @return Message
     */
    public function setMessageTitle($messageTitle)
    {
        $this->messageTitle = $messageTitle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get messageTitle
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMessageTitle()
    {
        return $this->messageTitle;
    }

    /**
     * Set messageBody
     *
     * @param string $messageBody
     * @return Message
     */
    public function setMessageBody($messageBody)
    {
        $this->messageBody = $messageBody;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get messageBody
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMessageBody()
    {
        return $this->messageBody;
    }
}
```

*Routing*

```
## api routes
app_getmessages: 
  pattern: /api/messages
  defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:messages}
```

*Database*

[image]

**NEW CODE:**

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/messages")
 * @Template()
 */
public function messagesGetAction()
{

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('XYGamingBundle:Message');
    $messagesArr = $repository->findAll();
    $json = new JsonResponse($messagesArr);

    if (!$json) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No messages found'
        );
    }

    return new Response($json);

}
```

**Solution**

```
// add to controller
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;

/**
 * @Route("/api/messages")
 * @Template()
 */
public function messagesGetAction()
{

    //$serializer = $container->get('jms_serializer');
    // $serializer->serialize($data, $format);
    // $data = $serializer->deserialize($inputStr, $typeName, $format);

    $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('XYGamingBundle:Message');
    $data = $repository->findAll();

    //$json = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');

    $json = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');

    //$json = new JsonResponse($messagesArr);

    if (!$json) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No messages found'
        );
    }

    return new Response($json);

}
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it seems the problem happens in the json_encode  part, because json_encode does not know how to access your private property, nor it knows how to use the getter.

For this you can use the Symfony serializer [Documentation for it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/serializer.html)
or the JMSSerializer Bundle (if you're building a complex API, you will sooner or later needs it)

Also you can use the `new JsonResponse($yourObject)` that would do the json_encode for you , as well as setting properly the HTTP headers (otherwise if you use Response , your json will still be advertized by the browser as being `text/html` )

Comment: Awesome but even this is returning empty `$messagesArr = $repository->findAll();` I was going to change it to that.

Comment: Awesome, I will check that out, FYI `JsonResponse` reuturns `HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json Date: Sun, 31 May 2015 05:34:08 GMT "[{},{},{}]"` still empty let me check out the bundle suggested

Comment: I installed the Symfony Serializer and I am still having an empty response? Let me update the OP with new code

Comment: NVM I got it will update OP. I write on node.js, php is okay but not very fun. I have to do this for a small project. Thanks though man you're awesome.